# SQL query in Music Brainz database

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I can do this query in Music Brainz database ([musicbrainz web site](https://musicbrainz.org/))

> Found the oldest Italian version (the result must include the release name, the release date and the country name (that is Italy))

I suppose some fields are `null`, so I used the function to coalesce to set its fields with hypothetical values (for years 9999, for months 13, for days 32)

The schema of the database is this:
[image]

This is the query code:

```
select release.name as nomeRelease, release_country.date_year as anno, release_country.date_month as mese, release_country.date_day as giorno, area.name as paese

from release left join release_country on release.id = release_country.release
         join country_area on release_country.country = country_area.area
         join area on area.id = country_area.area

where coalesce(release_country.date_day, 32) = 
(
    select min(coalesce(release_country.date_day, 32))

    from release left join release_country on release.id = release_country.release
                 join country_area on release_country.country = country_area.area
                 join area on area.id = country_area.area 

    where area.name = 'Italy' and release_country.date_month = 
        (
            select min(coalesce(release_country.date_month, 13)) 

            from release left join release_country on release.id = release_country.release
                         join country_area on release_country.country = country_area.area
                         join area on area.id = country_area.area

            where area.name = 'Italy' and release_country.date_year = 
            (
                select min(coalesce(release_country.date_year, 9999)) 

                from release left join release_country on release.id = release_country.release
                             join country_area on release_country.country = country_area.area
                             join area on area.id = country_area.area

                where area.name = 'Italy'
            )
        )
)
```

Looking at the rows of the database should come out as a 1983 release but inceve when I run the query as a result I have no rows

Comment: `where area.name = 'Italy'` ==>> area.name is (indirectly, via releas_country -> country_area) LEFT JOINed to release.. Putting it into a WHERE clause will force it to be NOT NULL, even if it doesn't exist (effectively turning the left join into a plain join). Try moving the area.name = 'Italy' to the `ON` clause of some LEFT JOINed table.

Comment: @joop          If I put `is not null` in the WHERE clause if the month is null does not return the lesser year

Comment: If your only goal is to find the oldest Italian song, why dont you just use `NOT EXISTS ( select older Italian song)` ?

Comment: Or use a WINDOW function `row_number OVER (ORDER BY release_country.date_year, release_country.date_month, release_country.date_day) AS rn` ...  and put `WHERE  rn = 1` in the outer query.